# Forms in Drupal

Tags: forms, drupal

I am using built in fields for creating form in Drupal. Can anybody help me about how and where to code that will be executed on submission of form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since Drupal provides you with everything you need on a form, why do you want to write code for it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am new to Drupal. Can you guide me how to do that?

Comment: Well, if you just want to add fields, you do not have to write code. Otherwise have a look at http://drupal.org, http://api.drupal.org and http://drupaldeveloper.in

Answer (score 2):

The way it works is suppose your form name is "XYZ", your form elements will be declared under XYZ_form function:

```
function XYZ_form($form_state){
....
}
```

Code for validation will go under XYZ_form_validate function:

```
function XYZ_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
..
}
```

And code to execute on form submit will go under XYZ_form_submit function:

```
function XYZ_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
...
}
```

More details can be found here: https://drupal.org/node/37775

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I have form that is created through content type. form created in content types will also use the same process (same name function) or any else way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom form you can make a module, and have the module provide the form.

You use hooks in the module to control parts of the form such as validation, submission and data processing.  You'll use the form API to help you write the code to provide the form elements.

If you want a form without coding you can use the webforms module.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I cannot create it through module. I have form that is created through content type section of Drupal. How should I code for it to be executed on submit?